# Navigate posts with different post type that are in the same categories

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, functions, mysql

I created two custom post types that share the same category taxonomy. I'm using `next_post_link()` and `previous_post_link()` to navigate through posts with the same category but it only works for individual post types.

I found the following code that links post types but there is no option for next and previous post to be within the same taxonomy/category as the current post.

```
/*
 * Replacement for get_adjacent_post()
 *
 * This supports only the custom post types you identify and does not
 * look at categories anymore. This allows you to go from one custom post type
 * to another which was not possible with the default get_adjacent_post().
 * Orig: wp-includes/link-template.php 
 * 
 * @param string $direction: Can be either 'prev' or 'next'
 * @param multi $post_types: Can be a string or an array of strings
 */
function mod_get_adjacent_post($direction = 'prev', $post_types = 'post') {
    global $post, $wpdb;

    if(empty($post)) return NULL;
    if(!$post_types) return NULL;

    if(is_array($post_types)){
        $txt = '';
        for($i = 0; $i <= count($post_types) - 1; $i++){
            $txt .= "'".$post_types[$i]."'";
            if($i != count($post_types) - 1) $txt .= ', ';
        }
        $post_types = $txt;
    }

    $current_post_date = $post->post_date;

    $join = '';
    $in_same_cat = FALSE;
    $excluded_categories = '';
    $adjacent = $direction == 'prev' ? 'previous' : 'next';
    $op = $direction == 'prev' ? '<' : '>';
    $order = $direction == 'prev' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

    $join  = apply_filters( "get_{$adjacent}_post_join", $join, $in_same_cat, $excluded_categories );
    $where = apply_filters( "get_{$adjacent}_post_where", $wpdb->prepare("WHERE p.post_date $op %s AND p.post_type IN({$post_types}) AND p.post_status = 'publish'", $current_post_date), $in_same_cat, $excluded_categories );
    $sort  = apply_filters( "get_{$adjacent}_post_sort", "ORDER BY p.post_date $order LIMIT 1" );

    $query = "SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts AS p $join $where $sort";
    $query_key = 'adjacent_post_' . md5($query);
    $result = wp_cache_get($query_key, 'counts');
    if ( false !== $result )
        return $result;

    $result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts AS p $join $where $sort");
    if ( null === $result )
        $result = '';

    wp_cache_set($query_key, $result, 'counts');
    return $result;
}
```

Usage

```
<?php
$prev = mod_get_adjacent_post('prev', array('post', 'custom1', 'custom2'));
$next = mod_get_adjacent_post('next', array('post', 'custom1', 'custom2'));
?>

<?php if($prev) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($prev->ID)?>">&laquo; Go back in time</a>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($next) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($next->ID)?>">Next: <?php echo $next->post_title; ?> &raquo;</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I navigate the posts with the same taxonomy?

Comment: A post, does it belongs to only one term. If not, how are you determining which term to use

Comment: The post belongs to 1 or more categories. I'm determining through what categories to cycle based on the current post categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take on things. I have scrapped your complete idea and went with an alternative solution which doesn't use SQL. I have done some testing and found my method to be much faster that the code in your question

### THE IDEA:

You first need to get the current post id, which I get through [`get_queried_object_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object). The post ID will be used to retrieve:

- The post terms the post belongs to with [`wp_get_post_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms). To speed things up, only the ID's of the terms will be returned. The first ID will be used (*you can modify the code here to decide which term will be used if a post have more than one term*) and this will be used to retrieve all the posts which has this certain term
- The post ID's of the posts that is directly adjacent to this post to determine and retrieve the next and previous post from this one

All the info above will be used in a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) with [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to retrieve all the posts that shares the term from the current post. In the function, the default taxonomy is `category` and the `post_type` is set to any to get all the posts that has this specific term

Again, to make the code faster and to safe on resources, we only going to get the post ID's as this is all that is needed

Now comes the important parts of the code. We now need to determine the following:

- The current position of the current post in the returned array of post ID's from the custom `get_posts` query. The function used here is [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)
- If there is a post before or after this post (*next or previous posts, the definitions are the same as for the build in functions [`next_post_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) and [`previous_post_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link)*), get the ID's of these posts
- Use the ID's with [`get_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) to retrieve the next and previous post's titles from the current post

Lastly will be to return the links. I have set messages if the current post is either the first or last post in the array and there are no next or previous post. You can decide what you want to do here, and for all that matters, the rest of the code

To make the code even faster and more efficient, I have made use of the [Transient API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) which you can read further on. I have also used the `transition_post_status` action hook to hook a function to delete these transients whenever the post status of a post change. This includes new posts being published, post being updated and post deleted/undeleted

### THE CODE:

Here is the code. This goes into your functions.php

```
function get_post_link( $taxonomy = 'category', $post_type = [ 'any' ] ) {

    $id             = get_queried_object_id(); // Get the current post ID
    $transient_id   = 'post_number_' . md5( $id . $taxonomy . implode( ',', $post_type ) ); //Create a unique transient id

    if ( false === ( $links = get_transient( $transient_id ) ) ) {

        // Get the terms a post belongs to
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $id, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) ); 

        // Use a tax_query to get all posts from the given term
        // Just retrieve the ids to speed up the query
        $post_args = [ 
            'post_type'         => $post_type,
            'fields'            => 'ids',
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'tax_query'         => [
                [
                    'taxonomy'          => $taxonomy,
                    'field'             => 'term_id',
                    'terms'             => $terms[0],
                    'include_children'  => false,
                ],
            ],

        ];

        // Get all the posts having the given term from all post types
        $q = get_posts( $post_args );

        //Get the current post position. Will be used to determine next/previous post
        $current_post_position = array_search( $id, $q );

        // Get the previous/older post ID
        if ( array_key_exists( $current_post_position + 1 , $q ) ) {
            $previous = $q[$current_post_position + 1];
        }

        // Get post title link to the previous post
        if( isset( $previous ) ) {
            $previous_post      = get_post( $previous );
            $previous_post_link = get_permalink( $previous );
            $previous_title     = '<a href="' . $previous_post_link . '">' . $previous_post->post_title . '</a></br>';
        }

        // Get the next/newer post ID
        if ( array_key_exists( $current_post_position - 1 , $q ) ) {
            $next = $q[$current_post_position - 1];
        }

        // Get post title link to the next post
        if( isset( $next ) ) {
            $next_post      = get_post( $next );
            $next_post_link = get_permalink( $next );
            $next_title     = '<a href="' . $next_post_link . '">' . $next_post->post_title . '</a></br>';?><pre><?php var_dump($next_title); ?></pre><?php 

        }

        // The returned post links 
        if( isset( $previous_title, $next_title ) ) {

            $links = [
                'previous_post' => $previous_title, 
                'next_post'     => $next_title, 
            ];

        }elseif( !isset( $previous_title ) && $next_title ) {

            $links = [
                'previous_post' => 'You are currently viewing the newest post', 
                'next_post'     => $next_title, 
            ];

        }elseif( $previous_title && !isset( $next_title ) ) {

            $links = [
                'previous_post' => $previous_title, 
                'next_post'     => 'You are currently viewing the last post', 
            ];

        }

        set_transient( $transient_id, $links, 7 * DAY_IN_SECONDS );
    }

    return (object)$links;
}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{

        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->options WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient%_post_number_%')" );
        $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->options WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient_timeout%_post_number_%')" );

}, 10, 3 );
```

### HOW TO USE:

You can now use the code as follows in you single.php. The default taxonomy is `category` and post type is `any`. If your custom taxonomy is called `mytax`, you can use the code like this

```
if( function_exists( 'get_post_link' ) ) {          
    $post_links = get_post_link( 'mytax' );
    echo $post_links->previous_post . '</br>' . $post_links->next_post;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! It's worthy of rep points! I tested your solution and it works perfectly. Is there a clever way to check first if a post has a category or no related posts? I'm thinking about using `has_category()` when using the function or `get_adjacent_post()` however I don't think that will work across multiple post types.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting you on this. Do you first want to check if a post has a certain category and if it has, show the next/previous post in that specific category.

Comment: I am using `if ($post_links->previous_post || $post_links->next_post)` when calling the function.

Comment: for my question I meant check if a post has any other posts in the same category or a category at all

Comment: You should use the code that I posted in "**HOW TO USE**" in your single.php. The check you are doing is already done inside the function. If there are no next or previous post, a custom message is displayed. The function uses `wp_get_post_terms` to get the categories of the post. It is faster and more global and works with all taxonomies. The function also uses a `tax_query` to check if there are any posts that has the same category and then retrieves them.

Comment: I think the code is confusing because it doesn't use functions like `get_the_category`.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the confusion. I am using the code in "how to use". The only problem is that I am wrapping the code in a class, in HTML. So  I added `if ($post_links->previous_post || $post_links->next_post)` before `<div class="my-class"><?php echo $post_links->previous_post . '</br>' . $post_links->next_post; ?></div>` to first check if there will be navigation otherwise don't show the empty div `my-class` Not sure if that's the best way to it.

Comment: You can simply modify the function as needed. The function uses very plain links, I have intentionally left out HTML markup as to give you the freedom to modify it. I would suggest that you extend the function itself as needed. That would be the better way to go here. Just remember, if you change any code in the function, simply update any post to delete the transient so it can be reset to your changes. I hope this helps